# actionlib error

Tags: actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm new to ROS and am having problems with the [actionlib tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Simple%20Action%20Server%20using%20the%20Execute%20Callback%20%28Python%29). After making the directory ./action/move_arm.action with this as the action file;

```
#goal definition
int32 goalState
---
#result definition
int32[] resultState
---
#feedback definition
int32[] feedbackState
```

attempting to generate the appropriate files using the command line prompt

```
$ rosrun actionlib_msgs genaction.py . move_arm.action
```

I get the following traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/actionlib_msgs/scripts/genaction.py", line 133, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/actionlib_msgs/scripts/genaction.py", line 72, in main
    os.makedirs(output_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 145, in makedirs
    head, tail = path.split(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 83, in split
    i = p.rfind('/') + 1
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

Is this a python problem? Should it be updated somehow?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35685/actionlib-error/) by [Damien90](https://answers.ros.org/users/2540/damien90/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-06-04

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bug in `actionlib_msgs`, and you should report it [here](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/newticket?component=common_msgs&type=defect&&common_msgs) with a link to this question. It seems the `output_dir` has no sensible default and/or the `-o` option is mandatory, but it is never checked whether the user supplies this option. Also, the `genaction.py` call in the linked tutorial is wrong.

I could make it work with the following command (run inside package `learning_actionlib`:

```
rosrun actionlib_msgs genaction.py -o msg/ action/move_arm.action
```

(BTW, actions use CamelCase by convention, so `MoveArm.action` would be a better name.)

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3